# VOX mic that emulates PTT

Tags: microphone

I have a radio that does not support VOX, but then I got the idea that there might be a VOX mic that sends the PTT when VOX is activated?
Basically a mic that will "push" the button for me.

Does that exist, both wired (3.5 mm) and Bluetooth (phone headsets) versions work with this radio I have.
Ridingtoo RT1

I have tried to find something like it but don't know what to search for.

Sorry about the tags, didn't know what to choose.
Maybe this is off topic here?

Answer (score 1):

After a quick Google I wasn't able to find any devices on the commercial market but it doesn't sound too hard to DIY.  Here's one: http://www.rason.org/Projects/basicvox/basicvox.htm

Basically you amplify the audio, use it to charge a capacitor and then use the voltage across the capacitor to control a transistor which keys the transmitter.

Comment: I'm surprised too there isn't such a device on the market. Building one on my own is of course an option, but not for now. I will not have time to build it and get all the parts in time for when I need it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your RT1 radio will not easily support VOX operation. The only control  of the PTT is on the main radio or the remote. There is no push to talk (PTT) connection brought out on the radio or the remote.

You could conceivably hack into either unit to bring out a PTT connection that could be interfaced to a VOX circuit but the radio does not bring out a microphone connection so that you can complete the project. It only has an earphone jack.

Based on our discussion in comments, you may have found some undocumented connections that could be usable for your VOX application. There is a [VOX adapter](https://www.radioparts.com/icom-vs-1) for Icom headsets that might be adaptable to your situation if you can find the proper connections on your radio. You would probably have to add a battery to the VOX unit since the Icom connections normally carry an 8 volt supply on the jack.

[image]

Comment: I'm surprised there is no PTT in the 3.5 mm jack. When I connect other headphones than the "stock" it's set to transmit. Something in the jack makes the device go in to transmit mode. Maybe that is just an unwanted effect and not a real feature.

Comment: @Andreas You may have found an undocumented feature!

Comment: Could be, but I don't have a real PTT headphone/mic/speaker to try with. So I can't know if it's a real feature or just shorting a wire.

Comment: And this "feature" or bug or whatever is the reason I asked the question in the first place

Comment: @Andreas You may wish to pick up a 3 and 4 conductor 3.5 mm plug and experiment a bit. If it has PTT  then there is probably a microphone connection as well.

Comment: There is for sure a microphone connection. The device has a mono speaker you push in your ear with a microphone attached a bit down the wire. This is then connected to the main unit, if you want to go corded, or you can use BT version

Comment: @Andreas Do they recommend a specific plug in earphone/microphone model? That might help decipher the wiring.

Comment: As far as I can remember there is nothing in the manual about using other headphones. Now that I think about it, the headphones that come with the device is mono, the ones I have tried to connect is stereo, that is probably why it goes to transmit mode